# Create DetailList of Group By LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to build a query in order to group some items by Product.

```
var ResultItemsGroupBy = ProductService.Get<Product>()
                             .ResultData.GroupBy(x => x.Product)
```

For Example, I have a list of n products :

```
List<Product> source = new List<Product>()
{
    new Product { Name = "Gasoline", Quantity = 10, Price = 30m },
    new Product { Name = "Gasoline", Quantity = 20, Price = 30m },
    new Product { Name = "Coca-Cola", Quantity = 5, Price = 10m },
};
```

Once I group them by product, I want to create a sublist with the details, for example:

```
List<GroupProduct> output = new List<GroupProduct>()
{
    new GroupProduct()
    {
        Name = "Gasoline",
        QuantityTotal = 30,
        TotalPrice = 60m,
        Details = new List<DetailProduct>()
        {
            new DetailProduct() { Quantity = 10, Price = 30m },
            new DetailProduct() { Quantity = 20, Price = 30m },
        }
    },
    new GroupProduct()
    {
        Name = "Coca-Cola",
        QuantityTotal = 5,
        TotalPrice = 10m,
        Details = new List<DetailProduct>()
        {
            new DetailProduct() { Quantity = 5, Price = 10m },
        }
    },
};
```

is it possible to create this sublist by running a query on the source?

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name;
    public int Quantity;
    public decimal Price;
}

public class DetailProduct
{
    public int Quantity;
    public decimal Price;
}

public class GroupProduct
{
    public string Name;
    public int QuantityTotal;
    public decimal TotalPrice;
    public List<DetailProduct> Details;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting some sort of error?

Comment: What have you tried? You need to add a `Select` to process the groups from the `GroupBy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the `source` data provided so beautifully in your question, along with the class definitions, you can just do this to get the result you want:

```
List<GroupProduct> results =
    source
        .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
        .Select(x => new GroupProduct()
        {
            Name = x.Key,
            QuantityTotal = x.Sum(y => y.Quantity),
            TotalPrice = x.Sum(y => y.Price),
            Details =
                x
                    .Select(y => new DetailProduct()
                    {
                        Quantity = y.Quantity,
                        Price = y.Price,
                    })
                    .ToList()
        })
        .ToList();
```

That gives me:

[image: results]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
  List<ProductDetail> details = ResultItemsGroupBy.Select(p => new ProductDetail()
  {
    Product = p.Key, //Value you grouped by will be assigned as the Product
    Price = p.First().Price, //Assumes the price is constant for all items in the group
    Quantity = p.Sum(q => q.Quantity) //Sum will add up all the items in the group
  }).ToList();
```

`Select` will return an `IEnumerable` of the operation which is performed on each group. In this case the "operation" is to create a new `ProductDetail`.

Comment: The OP seems to be summing price - the price in each product class seems to be the aggregate price and not the individual price.